# screensaver stopped activating

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen, screensaver

I'm running XUbuntu 20.04.1. Today I noticed twice after lengthy idle periods (a few hours) that the screensaver (blank screen) and lock on my laptop both failed to start. As far as I can tell, no settings have changed. Looking at the settings window presented by `xfce4-screensaver-preferences`, the screensaver itself is enabled. It's supposed to activate after the computer has been idle for five minutes. In the Lock Screen tab of the Screensaver Preferences dialog, "Enable Lock Screen", "Lock Screen with Screensaver", and "Lock Screen with System Sleep" are all enabled. The screensaver is running as `/usr/bin/xfce4-screensaver --no-daemon`, I assume started when I last logged in (16 May).

Are there other things I can look at to try to figure out what's going wrong, or should I just restart the screensaver and hope the situation improves?

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty bad experience with the screensaver that comes installed with xubuntu 20.04. (It wouldn't unlock after sitting idle for days.)

I've now simply disabled it and installed xscreensaver instead.

https://www.unixmen.com/installing-xscreensaver-ubuntu/